# Altering a large distance matrix to be just three columns

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have a large data frame/.csv that is a matrix with 42 columns and 110,357,407. It was derived from the x and y coordinates for two datasets of points, one with 41 and another with 110,357,407 and the values of the rows represent the distances between these two sets of points (the distance of each point on list 1 to every single point on list 2). The first column is a list of points (from 1 to 110,357,407). An excerpt from the matrix is below.

```
V1     V2          V3          V4         V5           V6          V7
1   38517.05    38717.8     38840.16    38961.37    39281.06    88551.03    88422.62
2   38514.05    38714.79    38837.15    38958.34    39278       88545.48    88417.09
3   38511.05    38711.79    38834.14    38955.3     39274.94    88539.92    88411.56
4   38508.05    38708.78    38831.13    38952.27    39271.88    88534.37    88406.03
5   38505.06    38705.78    38828.12    38949.24    39268.83    88528.82    88400.5
6   38502.07    38702.78    38825.12    38946.21    39265.78    88523.27    88394.97
7   38499.08    38699.78    38822.12    38943.18    39262.73    88517.72    88389.44
8   38496.09    38696.79    38819.12    38940.15    39259.68    88512.17    88383.91
9   38493.1     38693.8     38816.12    38937.13    39256.63    88506.62    88378.38
10  38490.12    38690.8     38813.12    38934.11    39253.58    88501.07    88372.85
11  38487.14    38687.81    38810.13    38931.09    39250.54    88495.52    88367.33
12  38484.16    38684.83    38807.14    38928.07    39247.5     88489.98    88361.8
13  38481.18    38681.84    38804.15    38925.06    39244.46    88484.43    88356.28
14  38478.21    38678.86    38801.16    38922.04    39241.43    88478.88    88350.75
15  38475.23    38675.88    38798.17    38919.03    39238.39    88473.34    88345.23
16  38472.26    38672.9     38795.19    38916.03    39235.36    88467.8     88339.71
```

My issue is that I would like to change this matrix into just 3 columns, the first column would be similar to the first column of the matrix with the 110,357,407 rows, the second would be the 41 data points (each matched up with a distance each of the first points to all of the others) and the third would be the distance between those points. So it would look something like this

```
Back   Pres   Dist
1          1        3486
2          1        3456
3          1        3483
4          1        3456
5          1        3429
6          1        3438
7          1        3422
8          1        3427
9          1        3428
```

(After the distances between the back and all of the first value of pres are complete, pres will change to 2 and will eventually work its way up to 41)

I realize that this will output a hugely ridiculous number of rows, but this is the format that I need to run some processes that are outside of R.

I tried using this code

```
cols.Output <- data.frame(col = rep(colnames(output3), each = nrow(output3)),           
            row = rep(rownames(output3), ncol(output3)), 
            value = as.vector(output3))
```

But there won’t be the same number of rows for each column, so I received an error (and I don’t think it would have really worked with my pres column needs). I tried experimenting with some of the rbind.fill and cbind.fill functions (the one in plyr and ones that others have come up with in the forum). I also looked into some of the melting and reshaping but I was very confused about the functions and couldn’t figure out how to implement them appropriately (or if they even are appropriate for what I need).  I would really appreciate any help on this as I’ve been struggling with it for a long time.

**Edit:** Just to be a little more clear about what I need. Take these two smaller data sets

back <- 1 dataset with 5 sets of x, y points

pres <- 1 dataset with 3 sets of x, y points

Calculating distances between these two data frames generates the initial matrix:

```
Back       1         2         3          
1          3427      3444      3451     
2          3432      3486      3476     
3          3486      3479      3486    
4          3449      3438      3484    
5          3483      3486      3486
```

And my desired output would look like this:

```
Back        Pres        Dist
1           1           3427
2           1           3432      
3           1           3486      
4           1           3449      
5           1           3483      
1           2           3444      
2           2           3486      
3           2           3479      
4           2           3438      
5           2           3486      
1           3           3451     
2           3           3476     
3           3           3486
4           3           3484   
5           3           3486
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Why not to show the problem in a smaller set. For example say, your are in dimension 3  `mat <- matrix(1:9,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
v <- -(1:3)` What is the expected result with this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks this is the kind of problem generally solved with some combination of `melt` and `cast` in the `reshape2` package. That said, with 100+ million rows, I'm not sure that that's the most efficient way to go in this case.

You could do it all manually as follows. I'll assume your data frame is called `df`, and the distances are in columns 2 to 42. See if this works.

```
d <- unlist(df[-1]) # put all the distances into a vector
newdf <- cbind(expand.grid(back=seq_len(nrow(df)), pres=seq_len(ncol(df) - 1)), d)
```

This will probably die unless you have tons of memory. The same holds for any simple solution though, since you have > 4.2 billion elements in the vector of distances. You can work on subsets of the full dataset at a time to get around this problem.

Comment: Finally got all this working. Essentially used this code but created a ton of subsets and eventually bound them all together using rbindlist() from data.table package. Took a while, and a bit messy, but I guess that's what happens with Big Data sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use `melt` on a small example:

```
require(reshape2)
a <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3)
a[, 1] <- 1:3 ## Pretending these are one set of points
rownames(a) <- a[, 1] ## We'll put them as rownames instead of a column
melt(a[, -1]) ## And omit that column when melting
```

If you have memory issues, you could write a for loop and do it in pieces, writing each to a file when they're completed.